# P5.js pixel density issue

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am making a sketch in P5.js that should have a pixel density of 1. The current state of this sketch it should be generating a tile that is 100x100 pixels of randomized brightness (like cable static) and displaying as a tile in the top left. Something seems off with the pixel density of the tile image I created though. there are large black lines appearing between each line of random pixels.

```js
function writeColor(image, x, y, red, green, blue, alpha) {
    let index = (x + y * width) * 4;
    image.pixels[index] = red;
    image.pixels[index + 1] = green;
    image.pixels[index + 2] = blue;
    image.pixels[index + 3] = alpha;
  }

function randomTile(size_x, size_y){
  let result = createImage(size_x, size_y);
  result.loadPixels();
  for (var y = 0; y < size_y; y++){
    for (var x= 0; x < size_x; x++){
      let brt = floor(random(256));
      writeColor(result, x, y, brt, brt, brt, 255);
    }
  }
  result.updatePixels();
  return result;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  pixelDensity(1);
  background(0);
  let tile = randomTile(100, 100);
  image(tile, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEuzF.png)

I have tried messing with the pixel density and looking up pixel density specific to images but I'm not really getting what is going on here.

Comment: gut instinct says the `index` var isn't doing what it should. Are you sure it's multiplied by `width` and not `size_x` or `size_y`?

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75089127/p5-js-pixel-density-issue#comment132510483_75089127), your indexing for a tile's pixels should be relative to that tile's width (`size_y`) rather than the p5 canvas `width`.

```js
function writeColor(image, x, y, w, red, green, blue, alpha) {
  const index = (x + y * w) * 4;
  image.pixels[index] = red;
  image.pixels[index + 1] = green;
  image.pixels[index + 2] = blue;
  image.pixels[index + 3] = alpha;
}

function randomTile(sizeX, sizeY) {
  const result = createImage(sizeX, sizeY);
  result.loadPixels();

  for (let y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
      const brt = floor(random(256));
      writeColor(result, x, y, sizeY, brt, brt, brt, 255);
    }
  }

  result.updatePixels();
  return result;
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 400);
  pixelDensity(1);
  background(0);
  const tile = randomTile(100, 100);
  image(tile, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Unrelated suggestions:

- Use `camelCase` rather than `snake_case` in JS.
- Use `const` when you don't need to reassign a variable (which is most of the time) and `let` everywhere else. Avoid `var`.
- When you have long argument lists, consider using an object to name the parameters (left as an exercise if performance allows it).